# Could not get an image from database php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, owl-carousel

Good day I just wanted to ask if why couldn't I get the images from this code though it work on me last time I used it.

Here's the function

```
/*ADDING SECTION*/
    public function AddHomeImages($images){
        try{
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO home(image) VALUES(:images)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":images", $images);
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;

        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

and this is how I upload it to the folder

```
<?php
/*---------DEVELOPMENT-----------*/
require_once '/database/database.php';


if(isset($_POST['btn-home-submit'])){
// $file = $_FILES['file'];

if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"images/sliding_images/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
}else{
    //nothing
}
$location = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if($user->AddHomeImages($location)){
    header("Location: admin-index.php?uploadedsuccessfully");
}   
}

?>
```

Now it can successfully upload and move the files to the folder and also on database now I want to show it up by using this codes

```
<?php

 require_once '/database/database.php';

 $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM home");
 $stmt->execute();


       <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-fullwidth">
                    while($userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        echo "<div class='item'";
                        echo "<img src='images/sliding_images/" .$userRow['image']. "' alt='UTEC PHOTO'>";
                        echo "<div class='slider-copy'";
                        echo "<h2>Architecture " .$userRow['id']. "</h2>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
          </div>

?>
```

But it only could get the `$userRow['id']` but not the image . Here's a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQZ8W.jpg)

There's no error actually on the console. Someone help me.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML in the page source for the "missing" image?  Is it the URL you expect?  In the network tab of the browser's debugging tools, what is the server's response for that URL?

Comment: When you view page source is the image linked correct?

Comment: geez sorry i forgot to put this ` echo "<div class='item'";` to this ` echo "<div class='item'>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace part of code.

```
echo "<div class='item'";
```

With below code(missing **>**).

```
 echo "<div class='item'>";
```